# Disable text field interaction with segue

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make textfield's user interaction disabled when the user tapped on tableview's row and the segue is applied.Where did I something wrong ? I am getting "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error when I select row at tableview.

here is my ViewController class and its necessary functions

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.selectedTrip = dateArray[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetailsVC", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toDetailsVC" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! detailsViewController
        destinationVC.kmField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
}
```

and kmField in detailsVC is like

```
@IBOutlet weak var kmField: UITextField!
```

Comment: You should put a breakpoint in and check to see which value is nil. Your problem sounds like it's before you get to the textField. It would be helpful to post whatever the compiler barfs into the console with your question, as the source of your problem is likely spelled out there.

Comment: I checked it and compiler sees kmField as nil.

Comment: Guessing the view's not rendered yet. Perhaps you might want to move the `kmField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` to DetailsViewController's `viewDidLoad/viewDidAppear` and deal with it there instead of trying to manipulate something that's not loaded yet.

Comment: Did you set this segue id on your storyboard toDetailsVC

Comment: yes I did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view has not yet been loaded from the storyboard when `prepareForSegue` is called, therefore your attempt to access the implicitly unwrapped optional `kmField` hits a `nil`.

It is generally a bad idea to access the internals of a class, such as a text field, directly from outside.

I would suggest you add a boolean property, say `isEditable`, that you can then use in `viewDidLoad` to set up your view controller:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? DetailsViewController
        destinationVC.isEditable = false
    }
}
```

By the way, by convention your view controller class should be `DetailsViewController`

```
class DetailsViewController {

    var isEditable = true
    @IBOutlet private weak var kmField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.kmField.isUserInteractionEnabled = self.isEditable
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello @efedoganay you need to understand the life cycle of viewcontroller. Function Prepare not initialize views property on screen, so you need to wait for sometime and make changes in other controller  **DetailsViewController** viewdidLoad Method.Or as @paul suggested set value in some variable and on the base of that set interaction property.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    kmfield.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to access internals of class like Textfields,buttons and labels which are taking reference from xib. until viewLoad those values are nil.

so better to take a boolean variable and make it false in tableview didselectrow.

based on that condition you can enable and disable the textfeild.

```
var isUserInteractionEnable = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
  kmfield.isUserInteractionEnabled = isUserInteractionEnable
}
```

Hope it helps.